# Pass value to second page (create & pass var)

Tags: asp.net

Good day, I need help and Don't know how to do.

I have 2 apsx pages: 1 aspx page calls the 2 aspx page.

But now in the 2 page I have a textbox with a btn to redirect to an url page passing the text box value as parameter for url report.

What I want is to move the the textbox to the 1 page 
and pass the value of the 1 page textbox to 2 page url.

Page 1 call page 2

```
TargetUrl="Page2.aspx"
```

Page 2

```
<input type="text" text="Keyword" id="keyword" value="">
<IFRAME id="frame1" src="http://server&KEY = 'keyword'>
```

Please provide some code or examples.

Regards

Comment: You should provide a better description of the scenario. Are you using .NET? PHP? None?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the QueryString:

```
//Page1.aspx
Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx?txt=" + textbox.Text);

//Page2.aspx
String text = Request.QueryString["txt"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Page.PreviousPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx) property to access the properties of Page1.

Something like this:

```
string previousPageText = Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("textboxname").Text;
```

Of course you would add the necessary checks that PreviousPage is not null and that FindControl returns a reference.

You should also note that the PreviousPage property only works if you do cross-page postbacks, so you probably should check the `Page.IsCrossPagePostBack` property first.

Comment: Thank You all

But the apsx pages i'm editing are in html code format, i think you are both refering to C#. 

Code is in HTML format with an aspx file extension

Please assist!

Comment: Are you coding html pages with the asmx extension? You really shouldn't do that since it will force asp.net to handle your requests instead of letting IIS do it itself.

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to your comments about your pages being pure HTML and not aspx:

You will have to use javascript to do this, for HTML has no support for your scenario itself.

In your first page you should place your textbox inside a form-tag with with methd="get" and target="page2.aspx". Now when you submit that form you will be redirected to page2.aspx but with a query string added.

In page2.aspx you should add a javascript function that will be called when the page is loaded, preferably in the OnLoad event of the pages body. In this function you could access parent.document.URL and extract the keyword from the query string, and finally you could update the source of the IFrame to use your keyword.

[See here](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object) for an example of a [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin that allows you to read query string variables.

Comment: Thanks, This is what i need to do but can't seem to pass the var value with the link. 

page 2:
function populateFields() {document.getElementById("txtkeyword").value = keyword; 
<BODY onload="populateFields()"> 

but Page 1 does not pass the value "test" to the var Keyword
<ignav:Item TargetUrl="myTrackingList.aspx?Keyword=test" TagString="" TargetFrame=""></ignav:Item>

Please Assist

Comment: Are you sure this is pure html? The <ignav:item> tag is not valid html